# vbs type mismatch: [string]

Tags: types, vbscript, mismatch

I have the following code giving me an error and I can't understand why.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDir = objFSO.GetFolder(strOrigDir)
Set colFiles = objDir.Files

For Each strFile in colFiles
Select Case Right(strFile,3)
    Case "rar"
        strTarFile = strFile
        intIsRar = 1
        Exit For
    Case "avi" or "mkv" or "mp4"
        strTarFile = strFile
        Exit For
    Case Else
        WScript.Quit
End Select
Next
```

I receive the message `Type mismatch: '[string:"avi"]'` on the `Select Case` line and I can't understand why. I have checked the value of strFile using VarType to make sure I'm not going crazy and trying to compare a string to something I shouldn't be (VarType returns 8). Any ideas why this is incorrect?

Comment: On which line does the error occur? What value does `VarType` return?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the syntax of the [`Select Case`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement. If you want multiple cases, you need to use a comma-delimited list:

```
Select Case Right(strFile,3)
    Case "rar"
        strTarFile = strFile
        intIsRar = 1
        Exit For
    Case "avi", "mkv", "mp4"
        strTarFile = strFile
        Exit For
    Case Else
        WScript.Quit
End Select
```

The "type mismatch" is probably happening because it is trying to evaluate `"avi" or "mkv" or "mp4"` as a Boolean statement.